# Makefile for struct birthday (linux module)

Tags: c, linux, module, makefile

I have write a linux modules with struct named birthday. I also try to create Makefile, but when I run it, just fail like this (the picture below).

I think my Makefile has a problem, but I can't solve this.

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/random.h>

struct birthday {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct list_head list;
}

struct birthday *my_bday, *tmp; *ptr;
struct list_head *pos;

int simple_init(void)
{
    int i, day, month, year;
    my_bday = kmalloc(sizeof(*my_bday), GFP_KERNEL);
    my_bday->day = 30;
    my_bday->month = 5;
    my_bday->year = 1984;

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&(my_bday->list));
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) {
        ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(*ptr), GFP_KERNEL);
    get_random_bytes(&day, 1);
    ptr->day = day % 31;
    if(ptr->day <0)
        ptr->day = ptr->day * -1;
    get_random_bytes(&month, 1);
    ptr->month = month % 12;

    if(ptr->month < 0)
        ptr->month = ptr->month * -1;
    get_random_bytes(&year, 1);
    ptr->year = (year % 2000) + 1900;
    if(ptr->year <0 )
        ptr->year = ptr->year * -1;
    list_add(&(ptr->list),&(my_bday->list));
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "Traversing the list using list_for_each()\n");
    list_for_each(pos, &(my_bday->list)) {
        tmp = list_entry(pos, struct birthday, list);
        printk("day = %d month = %d year = %d\n",tmp->day, tmp->month, tmp->year);
    return 0;
}

void simple_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");

    list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, tmp, &my_bday->list, list) {
    list_del(&*ptr->list));
    kfree(ptr);
    }
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);
```

And this is my code of Makefile:

```
obj-m += birthday.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules


clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post relevant parts as links. And dont post images of text!

Comment: And C and C++ are **different languages! Don't use tags of unrelated languages.

Comment: Put a semicolon after the struct declaration

Answer (score 0):

In make file it should be obj-m := birthday.o

birthday.c file has some errors and makefile
is good

Comment: Please elaborate your point a bit otherwise it will be closed as not an answer. 

`birthday.c file has some errors and makefile is good` then explain those errors.